# How to use an object with 'for-in' in python?

Tags: class, python-2.7, iteration

I have written a vector class, and I want to be able to write something like

```
x = Vector([1,2,3])
for i in x:
    #do stuff
```

Is there a special method like __ add __ that I can define to do something like this?

Comment: See also: [python special methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define `__iter__`:

```
>>> class Vector(object):
...     def __init__(self, vec):
...         self.data = vec[:]
...     def __iter__(self):
...         for i in self.data:
...             yield i
... 
>>> x = Vector([1,2,3])
>>> x
<__main__.Vector object at 0xb728210c>
>>> for i in x:
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
```

or in this case, you could get away with

```
>>> class Vector(object):
...     def __init__(self, vec):
...         self.data = vec[:]
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return iter(self.data)
... 
>>> Vector([1,2,3])
<__main__.Vector object at 0x914722c>
>>> list(Vector([1,2,3]))
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Etc.

Comment: In that case, using ``iter(self.data)`` in ``__iter__`` instead of the yielding loop is probably more efficient and shorter.